# How to hide a network adapter from the network popup of windows quick setting

Tags: windows-11

I am using Clash for Windows, TUN mode. It uses wintun and create a virtual network adapter. The network adapter shows in the network popup of windows quick setting like:

[Pic-Windows Quick Setting Network pop-up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jzro.png)

I hope to **hide** the adapter from the popup (NOT disable), like:

[Pic-Windows Quick Setting Network pop-up window-Target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BekHd.png)

Is it possible?